# Notify main page of variable changed by external js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to create a modular sign in script for some webpages I'm developing.  In short, I load the script on the main page, fire the main signIn function from a button press, and an overlay div is created on the main page which is managed by the external signIn.js.  The external js sets some sessionStorage variables that will be utilized in the main page.

The hope for modularity would be to have signIn.js handle the authentication from the database and have the main page do with the process of signing in as needed (in this specific instance, it gives users access to their projects).  Ideally, the sign in will not force a refresh of the main page due to other project goals.

The problem I'm encountering, is how do I notify the main page that the user has signed in without destroying any sense of modularity?

On top of other efforts, the most hopeful was attempting to create a custom event on the main page's document using `$(document).on('userSignedIn', function() {...});` but signIn.js apparently cannot trigger this event.

Any suggestions for how to accomplish this or am I just going about this entirely wrong?

**EDIT:**
So, this was definitely a scope related issue I was experiencing.  To flesh out the process, if anyone finds it relevant, signIn.js adds an overlay div to mainPage.html.  `$("#signInContainerDiv").load("signIn.html")` is used to load the sign in form into the page.  It turns out, when I was trying to reference `$(document)`, it was using signIn.html's document, and not mainPage.html's.  Upon that realization, I just created a div (signInNotify) on the mainPage that I bind the event to (`$("#signInNotify").on("userSignedIn", function() {...});`) and trigger it in signIn.js.

My own inexperience has conquered me, yet again.

Comment: `but signIn.js apparently cannot trigger this event.` why not? Triggering a custom event is by far the best solution in this scenario.

Comment: you need to check over several time with ajax call if not logged in then it is logged in or not at server side. No any other way to notify main page.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I don't know why it doesn't work, to be honest. Scope issues?  If i put `$.events.trigger('userSignedIn');` in the main page it fires but moving the code to signIn.js is nonfunctional.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi signIn.js is client side.  I considered a looping, timed check like that, but consider this case: `User presses 'Sign In' => overlay is displayed and check-loop initiated; User decides not to sign in => check-loop continues to run indefinitely`.  Doesn't seem very appropriate...

Comment: yes this can only be possible with socket. as we can see in stackoverflow realtime.

Comment: Maintaining a socket connection is ridiculous overkill for this. @rosst Is the `signIn.js` file loaded through an iframe? It's the only reason I could see it not having access to the parent document.

Comment: Agreed on the socket concept being overkill.  It's loaded into a div using `$('#signInContainer').load('signIn.html');`.  Running some more testing, this is definitely a scope problem.  signIn.js is referencing its own document and has no access to main page's document.  Attempting `$(document).parent();` in signIn.js yields nothing.

Comment: Could you update the question to incude the code of `signIn.html` - or at least a brief outline if you want to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery can help you out when it comes to this. Here's an example from the main page for `trigger`

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "custom", function( event, param1, param2 ) {
  alert( param1 + "\n" + param2 );
});
$( "#foo").trigger( "custom", [ "Custom", "Event" ] );
```

[jQuery Page Reference](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: As I mentioned, I attempted this but signIn.js will not trigger the event that is bound to the main document.

Comment: why does it have to be on `$(document)` -- insert a hidden div & trigger on that like you would document, in this case `$('#foo')`

Comment: Well, I guess it doesn't have to be on document; that was just an effort to keep things more modular (just have to bind to document as opposed to creating an element on each main page).  However, I tried this to no avail.    Calling `$._data($("#foo")[0], "events");` on main page shows the event but calling it in signIn.js yeilds `undefined`.

Comment: I have a different result, here's a jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/kwp5t3tv/)

Comment: Updated my question to explain a bit, but I was essentially on the correct path in the first place.  It was a scope issue and referencing a hidden div has resolved the issue (though, for some reason the events are being cleared, but that's another problem to rectify).  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use some library like [amplify.js](http://amplifyjs.com/), it has publish/subscribe functionality which can be useful for implementing the "observer pattern". You could also implement your own library for that, the code could be something like this:

```
// the implementation
function Notify () {
    this.listeners = {};
}

Notify.prototype.subscribe = function (event, callback, context) {
    this.listeners[event] = this.listeners[event] || [];
    this.listeners[event].push({ callback: callback, context: context || null});
};

Notify.prototype.publish = function (event/*, args...*/) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    (this.listeners[event] || []).forEach(function (x) {
        x.callback.apply(x.callback.context, args);
    });
};
// usage:
// an instance, or can be implemented as a singleton
var global_events = new Notify();
// wherever you want to be notified of login events
global_events.subscribe('login_success', function () {
    // do something with the arguments
}, myContext/*optional*/);
// after success login
global_events.publish('login_success', user_credentials, other_data);
// and all subscribers (listeners) will be called after this
```

I have used that code for similar purposes and also used amplifyjs a couple times, you can read more about [Amplify Pub/Sub](http://amplifyjs.com/api/pubsub/).

Comment: This looks quite useful.  I ended up getting it to semi-work with the nearly established route (using custom events), but may pursue this down the line.  Thanks for the snippet and pointing out Amplify.